# SSH keys for utility services on remote production server

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

For convienience I'd like to have a private SSH key on my remote server.

But doing that creates a vulnerability if the server were hacked.  Same as if I'd hard coded a password, anyone who broke in could take it and use it to access the service it was intended for.

Is there a mechanisim for temporarialy making a SSH key available to the target server in a terminal sesssion ?

I'm guessing there are solutions out there I just dont know about.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: I’m on mobile so just a short hint: the openssh authorized_keys format allow you apply restrictions on what actions are allowed when a specific key pair is used to log on - that mitigates some of the risks of compromised private ssh keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I was hoping to find.

SSH agent forwarding can be used to make deploying to a server simple. It allows you to use your local SSH keys instead of leaving keys (without passphrases!) sitting on your server.

https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/